# If a partner abandons his interest, what is the tax treatment for the remaining partners?

Tags: united-states, tax-law, corporate-tax-laws, gift, partnership

Suppose a partnership (such as an LLC with pass-through taxation) has three members.  Each owns an equal share of the business, which has a net liquidation value of $300,000.  One partner abandons his capital interest (valued at $100,000).  What are the tax consequences for the remaining members?  For example, is the $50,000 increase in the value of the capital interest of each remaining member taxed as income, as capital gains, as a gift, or not at all?

*Additional simplifying assumptions (if helpful):*

- The partnership has an operating agreement that permits abandonment under the same three conditions as IRC section 165 abandonment (imperfectly summarized [here](https://www.cpajournal.com/2016/10/01/partnership-abandonment/)).
- The partners' capital interests are fully vested, the LLC has no liabilities, and its assets are liquid.
- One of the remaining partners provides all LLC services and therefore pays income tax on profits, while the other remaining partner is inactive and therefore pays capital gains on profits.

Comment: Generally speaking, unless the LLC operating agreement provides otherwise, one cannot simply "abandon" a membership interest in the LLC without the permission of the other members, and the detailed  mechanics of what is or is not allowed by the operating agreement of the LLC to divest oneself of the membership interest and how it is done will influence the correct answer.

Comment: @ohwilleke These are interesting comments, thanks.  In this case, I am referring to an IRC section-165 abandonment (e.g., see: https://www.cpajournal.com/2016/10/01/partnership-abandonment/).  This form of abandonment does not appear to require permission of the other members or explicit provisions in the LLC operating agreement.

Comment: Section 165 abandonment is only possible when state law permits it. Usually, this is not an option under state law in an LLC. Tax law can't authorize you to do something, it only governs the tax treatment of actions that are possible under state law. The linked article overstates this possibility only to walk it back in the caveat section at the end.

Comment: @ohwilleke Okay, interesting. I've added several simplifying assumptions to the question to eliminate some of the complexity.

Comment: *"The LLC has an operating agreement that permits abandonment under the same three conditions as IRC section 165 abandonment"* The LLC operating agreement can't circumvent State law. If the state does not recognize abandonment, the LLC's operating agreement can't permit it, no matter what is written there.

Comment: @RonBeyer Ah, it sounds like abandonment may not be the concept I'm looking for.  Moving away from abandonment, it seems like a partner in a partnership or LLC should in general be able to "give up" his capital interest (perhaps with the permission of the other partners), with the underlying value then automatically redistributed to the remaining partners in some manner, perhaps proportionately to their capital interests.  Is this possible outside of an explicit sale or gift of the interest?  If so, what if any concept should I be using for it (forfeit, disclaim, dissociate,...)?